# Stuck in a .htaccess redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm setting up what I thought would be a fairly simple set of redirect rules using htaccess.

I've set up a redirect so that the root domain goes to a UK sub-directory. For example:

```
http://example.com
```

goes to:

```
http://example.com/uk
```

I'm now attempting the same thing but this time but for individual html files. See below:

```
http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/main.html
```

These should go to their UK counterparts:

```
http://example.com/uk/
http://example.com/uk/main.html
```

I have index.html working and redirecting nicely but doing a similar thing on main.html is introducing a redirect loop and I can't find figure out why. For the main.html redirect, I'm starting with a caret (^) so that should only match if main.html follows the domain directly.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
 php_value memory_limit 256M

## apc interferes with the autoloader
php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off

Options +FollowSymLinks

#Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.html /uk/ [R=302,NC,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/$  /uk/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^main.html /uk/main.html [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html  index.php?key=$1  [QSA,L]

AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I've tried numerous combinations with no luck. Can any one help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need only one rule in root .htaccess for this using regex alternation:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?:index|main)\.html)?$ /uk/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.